# Distance function for N-prism

Tags: geometry

Im looking for distance function that describes N prism. Im looking for pentagon prism, heptagon prism and octagon prism functions.

Function accepts vec3 position, which is observer position. Function returns one value, which is shortest distance to the surface of the prism.

Function doesnt provide where the pierce point is.

Function also might accept additional params like radius and height of the prism or it might be cosntant.

Prism center is always at [0, 0, 0] coordinate and it can be rotated or scaled as you want/need.

Formula can be used for [raymarching algorithm](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/67745/50875).

[Formulas for Triangular Prism and Hexagonal Prism I have found:](http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm)

```
// p is position of the observer, h.x is prism radius, h.y is halved height of the prism
float sdHexPrism( vec3 p, vec2 h )
{
    vec3 q = abs(p);
    return max(q.z-h.y,max((q.x*0.866025+q.y*0.5),q.y)-h.x);
}

float sdTriPrism( vec3 p, vec2 h )
{
    vec3 q = abs(p);
    return max(q.z-h.y,max(q.x*0.866025+p.y*0.5,-p.y)-h.x*0.5);
}
```

Im looking for any closer explination or ideas you might have, also both algebraic or programatic formulas.

**EDIT:**

Based on comments, I must admit, question might be difficult. Here I provided as many tips as I could. Because obviously I dont know the right answer...

- Provided formulas doesnt contain rotation or scale. Rotation and scale is constant.
- [What is max(x, y)](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/max.xhtml)? higher value is returned
- What is `abs(p)`? ([Absolute value](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/abs.xhtml)) If the observer position is [-2,-3,4] it becomes [2,3,4]. Dont know why...
- What is the number 0.866025? No idea, big question for me.
- `max(q.z-h.y, unknown);` first part is probably how far is the base of the object from observer

In addition, I will try to provide test tool that you can use to verify the formula.

Comment: It's going to take anyone a lot of work to even understand your question correctly. First, the formulas on the linked page do not give "distance to the nearest point" (in the usual sense) in most cases where the "nearest point" is on an edge or vertex of a polyhedron. The formulas seem to be correct only when you can drop a perpendicular onto a face, which is probably good enough for the algorithm since you can almost always do this when you are close enough to the object.

Comment: There are other things to work out, such as, if `vec3` has three coordinates, and `p` is a `vec3`, what is `abs(p)` and how can you set another `vec3` equal to `abs(p)`? Most of us would probably guess that `abs` means take the magnitude, but then the result is a single number and it makes no sense to say a 3-coordinate vector is equal to a number.

Comment: So maybe if you can work out how one of these formulas really works, you may figure out a much simpler question (about some detail) that you can ask that will help you, or at least be able to explain this one better.

Comment: It is really not nice you guys put my question on hold. I really tried to set it as clear as possible. Also the problem Im asking about is math based and its solution could be useful for larger community...

Comment: @David K Unfortunately, the program is almost impossible to debug :( how do you mean the sourced functions doesnt give the distance to the nearest point? like if the nearest point is on the edge, then the answer from function is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, the functions will give the "wrong" answer in many cases according to the usual definition of distance to an object. The function for the sphere is fine, but the distance to a box has to use the Pythagorean Theorem (with a square root) if you are not "over" a face of the box, and I see no evidence that the function does that. Whatever these functions are doing, it appears to be optimized for speed (as well it might, if it's graphics code for gaming) rather than for strict mathematical correctness. It seems _very_ specific to its application, not generally applicable at all.

Comment: Anyway, for one of us to do what you're asking, we'd have to debug (or at least reverse-engineer) the code enough to figure out what the given examples are supposed to be doing. Consider what you already said about how hard it is to debug the code. It's not going to happen. I think the only hope for this is question to migrate it to someplace where there are a lot of graphics programmers familiar with this particular style of raymarching, who may have a clue what the code is really supposed to do.

Comment: @David K thx for the support, I already find out some aproaches that might clarify some good solutions. Once I will find the answer I will post it also here. I will ask elsewhere ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution for an N-gon Signed Distance Function (SDF) is provided by Inigo Quilez [here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MtKcWW):

```
float nGon(in int n, in vec2 p, in float r) {
    // these 2 lines can be precomputed
    float an = 6.2831853 / float(n);
    float he = r * tan(0.5 * an);

    // rotate to first sector
    p = -p.yx; // if you want the corner to be up
    float bn = an * floor((atan(p.y, p.x) + 0.5 * an) / an);
    vec2 cs = vec2(cos(bn), sin(bn));
    p = mat2(cs.x, -cs.y, cs.y, cs.x) * p;

    // side of polygon
    return length(p - vec2(r, clamp(p.y, -he, he))) * sign(p.x-r);
}
```

Any polygon can be converted to a prism by "boxing" it by depth:

```
// for the distance result of any 2D SDF, returns a 3D prism for the 3rd axis position value v
float toPrism(in float d2d, in float v, in float size) {
    vec2 d = vec2(d2d, abs(v) - 0.5 * size);
    return length(max(d, 0.0)) + min(max(d.x, d.y), 0.0);
}
```

So a general function for an N-prism SDF is:

```
float nPrism(in int n, in vec3 p, in float r, in float depth) {
    float d = nGon(n, p.xy, r);
    return toPrism(d, p.z, depth);
}
```

More information [here](https://iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions2d/distfunctions2d.htm).